# Windows Universal Platform: Background task to check email

Tags: windows, email, uwp

I want to develop an app that has a background task that checks email servers (POP, IMAP, etc) for new email.

From what I can tell of background task, it is only allowed to run for a short time, and can be started only every 15 minutes if it is a timertrigger.

Since I want this app to run on all Windows devices, what is that proper approach to having a background task that can do this?  It doesn't seem possible at this point.

But since Windows devices are able to check email in the background, there must be a way.  Does anyone have any insights?

Comment: What's your question? You figured out that a bg task can only be called every 15 min - this is correct. More CPU intensive things may happen in the cloud, that's where notifications can be send which then show toasts or trigger a background task which handles the received payload.

Answer (score 1):

What you wish to achieve is a near real time  notification of user about a mail he received . You are right that Windows doesn't allow a background task to run at intervals lesser than 15 minutes . What you are looking for is [Windows Push Notification Service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/tiles-and-notifications-windows-push-notification-services--wns--overview?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) which can be used to send notifications from your *own cloud service* onto the device

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to use a background task working all time to get in real time the new emails in your case.
You must implement another approach may be using your own backend to implement push notifications to send a new notification when a new email is received.
If your provider has an API you can use it.